# Different configurations for \footfullcite and \cite in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In a document, I use both `\cite` for some citations, and `\footfullcite` for other ones. I have a `biblatex.cfg` file for the configuration. I'd like to be able to have distinct configurations for the two kinds of citations. Is that possible?

Example:

```
This is a \emph{normal} citation~\cite{Anon1}, and a footnote one\footfullcite{Anon2}.
```

In my `biblatex.cfg`, I would like things like

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}} % for \cite only
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textsc{#1}}    % for \footfullcite only
```

I am not only interested in distinct `\DeclareFieldFormat`s but also distinct `\AtEveryBibitem`s or `\renewbibmacro`s for instance. Or two distinct configuration files, this would be perfect too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\iffootnote{\textsc{#1}}{\mkbibbold{#1}}}
```

(untested as you didn't provide an MWE.

Comment: Argh! I don't know why but I was so sure that `\iffootnote` was for `\cite` commands used in a `\footnote` that I did not even try. Anyway, thanks!